# Edge and HTML Form Validation: how to remove "red square" around the input for elements in invalid status?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, microsoft-edge

On the picture (this is the Edge browser) field named BsMultiSelect have normal bootstrap `invalid` look (this is in css). The same I expect from "Input sample", but there Edge browser adds its own "red border" (it is not in css!) for elements in `invalid` state . How to disable this browser behaviour?

Chrome doesn't have such feature, doesn't add any `own styles` for `:invalid` elements.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you tryed `outline: 0` in css

Comment: It works! Thank you. It is interesting why Boostrap didn't add this rule by its own...

Answer (score 1):

You can remove this `outline` like this :

```
input {
    outline: unset;
}
```

Comment: Works also, as well as other global values `inherit` and `initial`, thank you. P.S. But I do not understand how and why all inheritation rules of global values works in this case, so ` input:invalid{outline: 0;}` looks simpler option. But thank you once more.